# memory leak node/socketio chat

Tags: node.js, socket.io, pm2

We have a chat built in nodejs/socketIO which works well. we use pm2 to start the app.
Our monitoring shows us memory usage increasing slowly and much more during chat exchange.
Yesterday we had around 1500 users in chat and suddenly memory took around 200 MB... and it stayed like that. When users in chat left it, we just got a small decline in usage.

socketio 4.0.1
node version 10.24.0
pm2 version 3.5.0
rhel 7

Memory has never be freed during the night until we started a "pm2 reload chat".

I tried to check memory usage :
PID USER     %MEM COMMAND
5195 root      2.4 node /appli/chatvideodiff/server/server.js
25836 root      0.3 PM2 v3.5.0: God Daemon (/root/.pm2)

node total : 1285928K
pm2 total : 913644K

and started a pmap to get more info.

There were not any issue but I would be interested to know what's causing memory "leak" so if you have an idea.

Thanks
Nico

[image: pm2 info during chat]

[image: mem usage before during chat]

[image: pmap during chat]

[image: mem usage after pm2 reload]

Comment: You must delete the variables you don't use anymore it's not a problem of node.js he has a strong garbage collector. It's a problem of your program  avoid circular references if possible, garbage collector could not find them (could find but it's not sure expecially when circular references create big and complex graphs

Comment: thanks @tommaso for these informations
I have few lines with "this." and in reading some papers I see that they are circular ref. I read also I can try in adding 

"use strict";
 
on top of code
what do you think about ?
thanks

Comment: it's difficult to say but could be that garbage collector doesn't delete the objects 'or at least try to find these ref' until memory space is available. node.js use a generational garbage collector so objects which doesn't die young will be checked always fewer times. if you chat remain active for a very long time garbage collector puts these object in a reserved area and this area will be checked fewer time 'as last resource before throwing OutOfMemoryError '. the more the object ref exists the more it will ignore them. Or it could be a error with your code i don't know i don't have your cod

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem I'm having as well. I came up with a solution:

`require('expose-gc')` npm module.

Nodejs has a built-in garbage collection method..

```
global.gc();
```

This approach removes any unneeded objects from your memory. As a result, please run a code on setInterval timelimit your timelimit for running a code.

```
 setInterval(function(){
             global.gc();
},10000);
```

---

Clean your RAM with this procedure.
please require expose-gc npm module.

---